# Newbie errors with my 1st workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow

I am learning this with a nice book but after following all steps I have the 3 following errors

```
Error   1   Activity 'onWorkflowActivated1' validation failed: Cannot resolve Activity 'Workflow1'. 
k:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSWF\TrainingApprovalSWF.cs   1   1

Error   2   Activity 'onWorkflowActivated1' validation failed: Activity 'onWorkflowActivated1' does not have CorrelationToken property set
k:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSWF\TrainingApprovalSWF.cs   1   1   

Error   3   Activity 'sendEmail1' validation failed: The correlation token for Activity sendEmail1 has an owner activity name which is not its parent
k:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow\TrainingApprovalSWF\TrainingApprovalSWF.cs   1   1
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to resolve the first error from the comments in this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms580283(office.12).aspx

The other two refer to CorrelationTokens, which are explained also in this link.

Comment: Hi ! Is there a solution when workflow is created with Sharepoint Designer ? I'm facing the issue than him (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/errors-were-found-when-compiling-the-workflow-the-workflow-files-were-saved-but) and it is still unanswered...