# Workflow variable limit (SP Online) - workaround for date calcs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

I'm apparently* hitting the 50 variable limit in a SharePoint 2010 workflow on a SharePoint Online site.

*I could probably kill off a dozen variables if I could do a varDate adjustment on the fly when creating a list item instead of creating varDatePlus5 as yet another variable. But... I can't figure out how to do it.*

*What can I present here that would help clarify in order to get input?*

*I just expanded the workflow and now I'm getting the "we published your files but nothing will work for you" error. The advanced view of the error shows me **activity IDs** that can't be resolved but I have no idea how to look up what those are. Although, to be honest, I would have thought I had more than 50 before the rewrite - this is a beast to take some fields from a list record and use them to generate 40 custom tasks (based on another list of task names) with estimated due dates, etc.

Error:
(0, 0) Activity 'ID4898' validation failed: Cannot resolve Activity 'ID4852'.)
(0, 0) Activity 'ID5009' validation failed: Cannot resolve Activity 'ID4852'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you Copy and Paste actions in the workflow?

Copy actions would cause “Cannot resolve Activity” issue.

Create actions manually and see if it works.

You can also refer to Brendan Murphy’s answer for “Cannot resolve Activity” issue in the thread below, cut and paste the entire workflow into the same window and compare the results.

[Cannot resolve Activity](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/cannot-resolve-activity)