# SharePoint Designer giving error while publishing SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013 farm if I try to publish Workflow for Document library getting below error.

(-1, -1) Type System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorExpression is not marked as authorized in the application configuration file.) (0, 0) Activity 'ID5' validation failed: Property "Condition" has invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The condition expression cannot be null.)

if I check for errors before publishing, there were no errors.
[image]

Comment: We have tried this but this not working. We are still getting the same error. What else can be missing? We have checked on the server, there is no update installed (KB4457916/KB4457035). Still we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this too, it started yesterday I think.  This [Microsoft link fixed it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update) for me.

The ​problem was caused by a .Net update.  If only these things were tested before they were released!

Below is my workflow error message - all workflows had stopped working in the Sharepoint Farm.

I was told that the MS fix in the above link, running IISRESET and also a WakeUp script fixed it.

[image: my workflow error message]

Comment: Yeah, I went through the link you suggested. could you please tell me where you inserted the code or how you fixed it. I am confused with the steps they mentioned in the article.

Comment: Tally and Chetan, the code referenced in the MS link above needs to be added to web.config file on the server. In our case, we had to update only the web front end servers, but depending on how your farm is configured then it may differ for you.

Answer (score 9):

As a solution for this problem, follow the instructions in [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update) by adding the code referenced to the web.config file on your SP server. In my organization's case, this was applied only to web front end servers, but check with your IT team to verify that against the topology of your farm.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft released a .NET update which causes lots of problems with SharePoint workflows.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/)

The article also contains a PowerShell-Script which fixes the problems caused by the patch: [Add-CodeDomAuthorizedType.ps1](https://gist.github.com/joerodgers/2302b394796c865818839d843bae2dad#file-add-codedomauthorizedtype-ps1)

Simply download the script on one SharePoint-Server and execute it in SharePoint PowerShell. The changes are automatically propagated within the entire farm (if you have mulitple servers).

**Important:** This script causes an IIS-Reset on every server. So SharePoint will not be available for some minutes.

Answer (score -1):

If a column has changed in SharePoint while Designer was opened, Designer may need a quick refresh.

This can be achieved by either restarting Designer, or by clicking the data refresh icon at the top left corner of the window.

[image: refresh]

Another thing I've done to fix Designer workflow errors is:

- Select All of the workflow
- Copy everything to clipboard
- Delete everything
- Paste everything back in from clipboard

Surprisingly, this fixes certain errors to do with designer workflow activities.

Comment: while this is a good tip, I'm pretty sure the error Chetan had was caused by a .net update Microsoft released - the fix for this bug is contained in my Answer.  Chetan just needs to know how and where to run the code.

Comment: This does not address the question asked by OP.