# SharePoint 2010 Workflow conditions not working upon Publish

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, error

I have some existing workflows that all of a sudden stopped working - around September 12, 2018. I tried many things: I looked at logs, .NET updates, cache issues, etc. and I can't get to the source of this issue. I went into the workflows and noticed that the conditions are the ones giving me an error when I try to publish, which is a big deal because my workflows depend on those conditions - IF conditions mostly.

Some of the errors I get say this below:

- FIRST WORKFLOW:

> (-1, -1) Type System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorExpression is not
>   marked as authorized in the application configuration file.)
>
> (0, 0) Activity 'ID179' validation failed: Property "Condition" has
>   invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The condition
>   expression can not be null.)
>
> (0, 0) Activity 'ID5' validation failed: Property "Condition" has
>   invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The condition
>   expression can not be null.)

---

- SECOND WORKFLOW:

> (-1, -1) Type System.CodeDom.CodeBinaryOperatorExpression is not
>   marked as authorized in the application configuration file.)
>
> (0, 0) Activity 'ID7' validation failed: Property "Condition" has
>   invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The condition
>   expression can not be null.)
>
> (0, 0) Activity 'ID12' validation failed: Property "Condition" has
>   invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The condition
>   expression can not be null.)

Do any of you know what is causing this? The workflows were working perfectly fine before.

*Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharePoint Designer giving error while publishing SharePoint Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249674/sharepoint-designer-giving-error-while-publishing-sharepoint-workflow)

Answer (score 1):

There has been an issue where a .Net patch causes workflows to fail.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/

And here is the KB article.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update