# Any known Issue with December 2018 Or November 2018 CU for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, cumulative-update

Any known Issue with December 2018 Or November 2018 CU for SharePoint 2013

have anyone seen any issue with the CU update ?

Answer (score 2):

The best source for this question is Todd Klindt's fantastic [SharePoint 2013 Build Numbers](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) page. You can find a column `Bugs, Notes and regressions` for every patch.

Your noted patches do not have any specific drawback, except the [.NET Security Patch issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249674/sharepoint-designer-giving-error-while-publishing-sharepoint-workflow). But this is not a SharePoint-CU specific issue, it was caused by a Windows .NET Security Patch.

This also matches my personal experience. No bugs have been reported by customers.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the CU ([Dec 2018](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/12/11/december-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/) & [Nov 2018](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/11/13/november-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)) are pretty much solid as i have not seen any issue regarding this. It is safe to install one of these.

Before installing these CU make sure couple of things.

- You farm should be SP1 Level before installing these CUs.
- If your farm has been on a patch level lower than July 2015 CU ensure to read the following [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/07/15/important-psconfig-is-mandatory-for-july-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013/).
- If you are using SharePoint Server bits then no need to install SharePoint Foundation bits as these are part of it.

It is always highly recommended that always apply the cu in lower farm and perform full testing.