# Can not publish workflow but can not find the errors

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, error

I try to publish a workflow but it says there are some errors, at the advanced button I see this message:

```
(0, 0) Activity 'ID4239' validation failed: Cannot resolve Activity 'ID4102'.)
(0, 0) Activity 'ID4230' validation failed: Cannot resolve Activity 'ID4102'.)
```

But when clicking at verifying errors it says that there are no errors.

How can publish the workflow?

How can I find which activities are the id 's exposed by the error message?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** You should not copy/paste your SP workflow actions/conditions.

**Resolution :** Try this one hopefully, close your workflow tab and refresh the SharePoint designer. Open the workflow and publish the workflow now, If any error now it will be showing the error or we can spotted the error area automatically.

**Note:** : You need to save your changes before the closing the workflow.

Comment: If the above answer is satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste it from the old workflow?

If yes, then simply cut and paste the entire workflow into the same window. Then try to publish it. If the issue  still persists, then open all the dynamic variables and just click on Save without doing any changes. Then publish the workflow.

Here are the references for a similar issue under which they just cut/paste the workflow in the same window and the issue was resolved.

1. [publishing 2010 workflow with SPD2013 get error "SharePoint Designer 2010 Errors were found when compiling the workflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/75dceb7c-ef3d-4233-ae02-b684ec68f62e/publishing-2010-workflow-with-spd2013-get-error-sharepoint-designer-2010-errors-were-found-when?forum=sharepointcustomization)
2. [Cannot resolve Activity](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/cannot-resolve-activity/187067#187067)